# Font-awesome showing square instead icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I need to change the font-family to some DropDownList I have, icons are visible until I change the font-family. Every font-family I choose doesn't work for the icon, and so I always see a square instead, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the source code?

Comment: most probably u want to use icon that isn't exist in your included font awesome library  , you have to show us the code

Comment: Check your console for a 404 error, it maybe that you are not linking correctly to the fonts.

Comment: The Font Awesome library uses a special font there all the icons are present. Changing the font to a system font will most likely result in missing icons, since they don't support them.

Answer (score 7):

> For `<i>` tags, put priority to use FontAwesome **font-family**

```css
body * {
font-family:'tahoma'!important;
}

body i {
font-family:'FontAwesome'!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa fa-male"></span> <span>Male</span> 
<br>
<span class="fa fa-female"></span> <span>Female</span>
<hr>
<i class="fa fa-male"></i> <span>Male</span> 
<br>
<i class="fa fa-female"></i> <span>Female</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Include font awesome in your `<head>` tag, like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">`
2. Use icon exactly like this: `<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>`, no more, no less, nothing in between, don't change `<i>` to `<span>` or change it's `font-family`. If you want to update colours, stylings, I recommend to add new class to it and update this way.

Comment: `opensource.keycdn.com seems to be down!`

Answer (score 1):

It could also be which link you are using. Some icons are from newer releases and don't work on old links of the repository.

Make sure that the cdn you're using is the newest.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and traced the cause to some icons being classified as ["brand icons"](https://fontawesome.com/icons?s=brands).

In my case, font awesome's "solid icons" worked prefectly however any "brand icons" I used rendered as rectangles. I resolved the issue by using the "all" font awesome CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" />
```

As well as replacing the class `fa` with `fab` where ever branded icons were being used:

```
<i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -3):

Try www.yourwebsite.com.
According to me its due to HTTP
so you have to make your website secure from your C-panel (HTTPS).

Comment: Please explain more. To me, spotting the relation between your answer and the problem described in the question is somewhat difficult.